# Is there a way to write static type guards with instanceof check?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, static-methods

I wanted to have some sort of generic/reusable way to check for error instances so I wouldn't have to write

```js
try {...}
catch (error) {
  if (!(error instanceof Error)) {
    throw error;
  }
  if (!(error instanceof CustomError)) {
    throw error;
  }
  // handle `CustomError` there
  ...
}
```

So I wanted to write a generic typeguard for this.
The attempts are there: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUQE4bhgPJ7DAYQBsBDFFRAUwA8pqwATKqATwAdq5hECdEAXkTsuPPlhwA+ABTVJGAFyJwAazBwA7mAA0NBaQopl-YuUpCJhAJTL5hZFVOGLAbwCwAKEQ-EGalAgGEj2AjBgKFBkkNy8oWZGXgC+Xl4Q5lREIJFwALamNPSMLFYCHt6+kWSwEI6mcgrKahratvoOqCIAFp3lvv1+AUEhCsgRUTHiUD0oXv0pngtAA

At first I assumed I can use a static method which would propagate to all sub-classes if written like this:

```js
class CustomError extends Error {
  static isError(error: unknown): error is this {
        return error instanceof this
    }
}
```

My rationale was [`this` within static methods refers to the class itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#calling_static_members_from_another_static_method) so it should work across all subclasses.
But typescript thinks the other way:

```
A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.
```

Then I've tried to write a generic function instead:

```js
function isError<ErrorClass extends typeof Error = typeof Error>(
  error: unknown,
  errorClass: ErrorClass = Error
): error is ErrorClass {
  return error instanceof errorClass;
}
```

However I have no idea how to tell typescript that the second argument is the class itself, not the instance type.
I may be missing something, but both of these approaches should give consistent type guards at the call signature, i.e. `this` in `CustomError.isError(error)` would always be of type `CustomError`, while `isError(error, CustomError)` ensures `error` is of type `CustomError`.

Comment: Seems like a lot of pain just to abstract `instanceof`...

Comment: This is just an example and I wouldn't say writing `if (!(error instanceof Error)) { throw error }` isn't painful, considering it is required in every single `catch` block. But the underlying issue is having a signature of a static method to refer to the current class, the most obvious example is alternative constructors on an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same approach as the stand alone function; you just need to add a `this` parameter to the static function. This parameter is just a TypeScript annotation used to specify the type of `this` in a function or method, and can be used as an inference source.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    static isError<T extends CustomError>(this:  new(...a: any[]) => T, error: unknown): error is T {
        return error instanceof this
    }
}

try {
    throw new CustomError("Custom Error thrown.")
} catch (error) {
  if (!CustomError.isError(error)) {
    throw error
  }

  error.isError
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZV6ApgB5IEB2AJjNrvgN4CwAUNK9MmEgJbDRcQ08AHgAqhEuSpxEqTDjwA+ABRIAFvwBcrMgQDuSgHRGwWsGQCeAbQC6ASmgBeBdBEAaQvKxb4ZANZkUXTJbLQJPPhgxRhY2WKwCJHgsMg9aPjIOMmACFAAzaDV+ZliAX2YypmYkLHNoaNi1XF1oHWaEZHRBLCUAInbZaC6C1SayAx7bcuhgTmBVaCUw2nt6vnylAEJ+zs8Dfi7Fz1sV4rZGwNS8U4rTpbw9gU9yoA)

Comment: The problem is this code assigns the signature of the constructor to the `error` variable. Whereas `error` must be inferred as an error's instance.

Comment: @BillerBuilder Not sure I understand what you mean. `error` will be narrowed based on the class `isError` is invoked on

Comment: Look at the at the tooltip of the `error` symbols in [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZV6ApgB5IEB2AJjNrvgN4CwAUNK9MmEgJbDRcQ08AHgAqhEuSrQyBAO4AKAHTKwALmhgyATwDaAXQCU0ALwA+OIlSYceU-KQALfupEAaQjazr4ZANZkUWTIDdQJPPhgxRhY2WKwCJHgsMg9aPjIOMmACFAAzaEd+ZliAX2YypmYkLC1oaNjHXFlpOQtkdEEseQAiBHa0aE6ChyayRW6DcuhgTmAHaHkw2iN6vnz5AEI+q07Ffk7FzwMV4rZGwNS8U4rTpbw9gU9yoA).

Comment: @BillerBuilder my bad. Fixed

Comment: Change your example code to [this one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZV6ApgB5IEB2AJjNrvgN4BQ00yYSAlsNOxDXgDwAVQiXJU4iVJhx4AfAAomzaEgAWPAFzQyBAO7R5AOmNgtYMgE8A2gF0AlNAC8s6IIA0S5gRlYt8MgDWZCi6ZEp2Wt603DDCjMrQWARI8FhkhD7cZKxkwAQoAGYq6hAA3EoAvgxVDKCQ1ERiBBR8+MSklDAIyOit0HQ1SFgW-UpquPo6+t1SrfIARDPo0H3jIWSG83blFdDAbMCqBlF4DvHcRfIAhEvStIY8cydYdmeexRMZtOXMVczAKGyKBABEMIBQAHN5AADW5fPDQVTmCggihaAAkdGehjQBCgYAhBAq0O21QYDCGI3Oa0mehWjUozT6CwwokZFBWmRpGy2Oz2ByO8meb2Y7EuV1ZTRaPgevB8Qp8r1GCRp8KwP2gfz2gIgwNB4Kh0NZHQozTViORqIxWJluPxhOJpKqQA) and I'll accept your answer.